# how to send the ouput of wso2cep to REST api?

Tags: rest, activemq-classic, wso2-cep

I am working with wso2cep3.1.0. I am taking the input by subscribing to ActiveMQ. But I want to output the contents of wso2cep to REST api. How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP event output adaptor for this purpose[1]. This adapter will generate HTTP GET request. You can dynamically inject attributes from streams to the request with the following fix[2]. Fix is already available in public repository in github.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Output+HTTP+Event+Adapter

[2] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-998